# WShell.Run returns 143

Tags: vbscript

I am calling java code from VB script using WShell.Run. It returns a code 143. What does it mean? Where can i get the list of error codes that run method can return?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the reference to [System Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> ERROR_SAME_DRIVE 143 (0x8F) The system cannot join or substitute a
>   drive to or for a directory on the same drive.

**P.S.** I think that the next notes are out of the question, but just in case...

Just to note that `Err` object has "dummy" `Description` (*Unknown runtime error*) for most codes. If you like to get filtered list with all sensible descriptions, you can do something like this:

```
With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Const DUMMY = "Unknown runtime error"
    ReDim aryLines(15999)
    Dim cnt, i, w, h
    cnt = -1

    .Navigate "about:blank"
    .Document.Title = "Error Codes " & String(100, Chr(1))
    .ToolBar        = False
    .Resizable      = True
    .StatusBar      = False
    .Width          = 420
    .Height         = 380

    With .Document.ParentWindow.Screen
        w = .AvailWidth
        h = .AvailHeight
    End With
    .Left = (w - .Width ) \ 2
    .Top  = (h - .Height) \ 2

    Do While .Busy : WScript.Sleep 200 : Loop

    On Error Resume Next
    With Err
        For i = 1 To 15999
            .Raise i
            If .Description <> DUMMY Then
                cnt = cnt + 1
                aryLines(cnt) = AddZero(i) & .Description
            End If
            .Clear
        Next
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    ReDim Preserve aryLines(cnt)
    .Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<pre id=x>" & Join(aryLines, vbNewLine)
    .Document.Body.Style.overflow = "auto"
    .Document.All.X.Style.fontFamily = "Verdana, sans-serif"
    .Visible = True
End With

Function AddZero(nVar)
    AddZero = "<b>" & Right("00000" & nVar, 5) & "</b> "
End Function
```

[image: screen capture result]

Answer (score 0):

this code returned by your java application. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

*The following VBScript code does the same thing, except it specifies the window type, waits for Notepad to be shut down by the user, and saves the error code returned from Notepad when it is shut down.*

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Return = WshShell.Run("notepad " & WScript.ScriptFullName, 1, true)
```

---